# loop through dynamic nested javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a dynamic array of objects like this:

```
[
    0: {id: "1", name: "name1", client: "data"},
    1: {id: "2", name: "name2", client: "data"},
    2: {id: "4", name: "name3", client: "data"},
    3: {id: "5", name: "name4", client: "data"},
    4: {id: "6", name: "name5", client: "data"},
    5: {id: "7", name: "name6", client: "data"}
]
```

And I want to extract values from that table, like name1, name2... and data...

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)

Comment: @Virginia it's not duplicated, my object have a dynamic keys which hold already other objects

Comment: @gogaz I tried Object.keys() and then I mapped through the result, but it's not what I expected

Comment: Your keys are not dynamic, values are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
let arr =[
     {id: "1", name: "name1", client: "data"},
     {id: "2", name: "name2", client: "data"},
     {id: "4", name: "name3", client: "data"},
     {id: "5", name: "name4", client: "data"},
     {id: "6", name: "name5", client: "data"},
     {id: "7", name: "name6", client: "data"}
];

for (obj in arr) {
    console.log(arr[obj]["name"]); // will get the name. 
}
```

You can also do inside the loop: `let client = arr[obj]["client"];` if you need the client value (for example)

Comment: let's suppose that I want to display then in an angular html template...then how it would work? because I tried but it did not worked when I looped through them with *ngFor loop even when I used keyvalue pipe

Comment: I'm don't have experience in angular yet (just java-script stand alone project till now) - guess it should be new question

Comment: I already asked it but I did nto got any answer, anyway thanks for the help ;)